# Reset an open serial port

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I am reading data from a serial port, sent by an arduino.

I have two files, which I use separately to write some code and try differents things.  In one of them, I read the data and I draw it using a matplotlib figure. After I finish using it, it remains connected to my computer and sending data. So, what i need to do is to "reset" the port. This is, close the opened port and open it again, and stop it from sending data so I can use the arduino to try some modifications in the code of this file.

So to accomplish this, i mean, to reset the port, i created another file and wrote this code:

```
import serial

print "Opening port"

try:
  serial_port = serial.Serial("com4", 9600)
  print "Port is open"

except serial.SerialException:
  serial.Serial("com4", 9600).close()
  print "Port is closed"
  serial_port = serial.Serial("com4",9600)
  print "Port is open again"

print "Ready to use"
```

But this code does not seems to work.The port is still connected and sending data. So, it means that I can not close the port with my code,and then reopen it again.

What am i doing wrong? How can I stop the arduino from sending data? Or how can I reset thw arduino, maybe?

Hope you can help me.

### ----- EDIT -----

I accomplish to identify the real problem that i am having, and it is not what i thought. The problem was not that the port was open despite that i use the `close`function that Pyserial have. The real thing is that the port is closing as I want, but the device (the arduino) is still sending data. So, i changed the code to reproduce the situation.

This is the code:

```
print "Abriendo puerto"

ser = serial

try:
  ser = serial.Serial("com4", 9600, timeout = 1)
  serial_port = "Open"
  print "The port %s is available" %ser

except serial.serialutil.SerialException:
  print "The port is at use"

  ser.close()
  ser.open()

while ser.read():
  print "Sending data"

ser.setBreak(True)
time.sleep(0.2)

ser.sendBreak(duration = 0.02)
time.sleep(0.2)

ser.close()
time.sleep(0.2)
print "The port is closed"

exit()
```

With this code, what i do is:

1) I open the serial port

2) If the device is sending data, I print "Sending data"

3) After 1 sec, I try to close the port and stop the device from sending data

I tried these last two thing with the `close` function to close the port, and reading the docs I tried with `setBreak` and `sendBreak` as you can see in the code above (i left them on purpose). But the device is still sending the data, which means that the code does not work.

So, is there a way to tell the arduino "stop sending data", or can i reset the device?

Comment: *"What am i doing wrong?"* -- You're not explaining what you mean by *"not working"* and what you do expect.  What is it that you expect a *"reset"* to do?  Why do you think you need it?  You're probably asking an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  IOW you're trying to solve the wrong problem and asking the wrong question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: I have problems following your description (e.g. overuse of *"it"*).  You assume too much and omit too much.  What makes you think that a *"reset"* of the serial port is going to *"stop the arduino from sending data"*?  (The destination port has little/no control over the sending port.)  *"Or how can I reset thw arduino, maybe? "*  -- What do you want to do?  You could pause the data transfer using HW flow control.  You could implement a transfer protocol.  You could add a control line to force a hard reset of the Arduino.

Comment: Thank you for your answer again. You where right, my question was not clear. So i edited again with the real problem that I am having, which i identified thanks to you and the other users that answered too. Thank you again and hope you can help me.

Comment: I don't use Arduino stuff, so I don't have an answer for that.  Serial links (and communication links in general) can be classified in two configurations.  (1) Master-slave. The master device grants permission to the slave to send.  Often this is a simple request (from master) and response (by slave) dialog. (2) Peer-to-peer.  Anybody can send to anybody; you chose to accept requests or not, and respond or not.  So, which topology do you want to use?  Seems like you need to implement a protocol handler in the Arduino so that it will accept a command to shut up.  Or use modem control lines.

Comment: There's also the client-server model, but that doesn't fit your simple setup.

Comment: I have a similar problem.  I get a reset signal by opening /dev/ttyUSB0 (Nano) but not for /dev/ttyACM0 (Uno) on a Raspbian Jessie system.  Question posted here:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/74252/jessie-how-to-make-python-open-of-dev-ttyacm0-send-rst-signal-like-it-does-wit

Answer (score 5):

I do a very similar thing, two ways with success.

The first way is to let the Arduino send data continuously. The problem here is when your python code wakes up and starts to read from the serial port, the Arduino might be anywhere in its procedures. The simple solution is to modify the Arduino code to send some kind of "restarting" line. All your python code needs to do in this case is wait for "restart", then read real data until it again sees "restart". I had noisy lines so my code read (and parsed) through multiple cycles to make sure it got good data.

```
resetCount = 0;
while resetCount < 3:
    line = s.readline().rstrip("\r\n")
    if string.find(line, "restart") != -1 :
        resetCount += 1
    elif resetCount > 0 :
        fields = string.split(line, " ")
        dict[fields[0]] = fields
```

The second way is to implement a command-response protocol with the Arduino, wherein the Arduino sends data only when requested. In this case your python code sends a command to the Arduino ("RT" in the example below) and then reads data from the Arduino until it sees a "completed" line or it times out.

```
        dict = {}
        regex = re.compile('28-[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}') # 28-000005eaa80e

        s = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0', 9600, timeout=5)
        s.write("RT\n");

        while True:
            line = s.readline().rstrip("\r\n")
            print line
            if string.find(line, "completed") != -1:
                break;

            fields = string.split(line)
            if (regex.match(fields[0]) != None and len(fields) == 4) :
                dict[fields[0]] = fields
        s.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that when you close the port, data is still coming from the arduino and being buffered by the operating system. There is a short delay between your script calling close() and the device driver actually shutting stuff down.

An immediate re-open may allow the driver to carry on without resetting its buffer. This is the device driver buffer, not the one seen by the Python serial port instance.

If you wait for at least a couple of seconds after the call to close() before you try to call open() then the behaviour should be as you hope.

I have just spent most of the day working out that this is what had been preventing my code from working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do a serial_port.open() immediately after creation to actually open the port.

It also looks like it just opens the port and exits if successful.  Maybe I'm missing something here.  I've never used pySerial, I'm just going by the docs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No, just by using `serial_port = serial.Serial("com4", 9600)`, the port is open.

Comment: Oh, I was going by the documentation which states: "The port is immediately opened on object creation, when a port is given. It is not opened when port is None and a successive call to open() is required."  This is under the class serial.Serial section. [link](http://pyserial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.open) That's odd that it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the handle to close the port instead of invoking the constructor again.
If you the port is open and you call serial.Serial("com4", 9600) it will attempt to re-open the port again and fail.

If serial_port was assigned successfully then serial_port.close() should close it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried this and i still can make it work. I edited the question to explain better my problem. Hope you can help me